# H2ONaiveBayesEstimator predicting unexpected result

Tags: python, h2o

I have a data frame with four columns: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'target', where target is the sum of the first three values.
I train H2ONaiveBayesEstimator with this data frame, and try to predict the result for a similar data frame. But the result is unexpected.

I tried the same data frames with LinearRegression, and it gives the expected predictions.

Why H2ONaiveBayesEstimator gives such a prediction result, value 27 for 20 rows?

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import h2o
from h2o.estimators import H2ONaiveBayesEstimator
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

train_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": list(range(10)),
        "b": list(range(10)),
        "c": list(range(10)),
        "target": [i + i + i for i in list(range(10))]
    }
)

pred_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": list(range(10, 30)),
        "b": list(range(10, 30)),
        "c": list(range(10, 30)),
    }
)

train_data = train_df.values
features_data = train_df.drop('target', axis=1).values
target_data = train_df['target'].values

pred_data = pred_df.values

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(features_data, target_data)
predictions = lr.predict(pred_data)
print(predictions)

print('\n----\n')

h2o.init()
train_frame = h2o.H2OFrame(train_data, column_names=list(train_df.columns))
nbm = H2ONaiveBayesEstimator()
train_frame['target'] = train_frame['target'].asfactor()
nbm.train(y='target', training_frame=train_frame)

pred_frame = h2o.H2OFrame(pred_data, column_names=list(pred_df.columns))
predictions = nbm.predict(pred_frame)
print('\n----\n')
print(predictions.as_data_frame())
```

train data frame:

```
   a  b  c  target
0  0  0  0       0
1  1  1  1       3
2  2  2  2       6
3  3  3  3       9
4  4  4  4      12
5  5  5  5      15
6  6  6  6      18
7  7  7  7      21
8  8  8  8      24
9  9  9  9      27
```

pred data frame:

```
0   10  10  10
1   11  11  11
2   12  12  12
3   13  13  13
4   14  14  14
5   15  15  15
6   16  16  16
7   17  17  17
8   18  18  18
9   19  19  19
10  20  20  20
11  21  21  21
12  22  22  22
13  23  23  23
14  24  24  24
15  25  25  25
16  26  26  26
17  27  27  27
18  28  28  28
19  29  29  29
```

Result for H2ONaiveBayesEstimator:

```
    predict             p0             p3  ...           p21           p24       p27
0        27   3.180305e-65   7.583358e-53  ...  6.076669e-06  1.098688e-02  0.989007
1        27   6.040575e-77   2.893040e-63  ...  1.522156e-08  5.527786e-04  0.999447
2        27   1.135940e-88   1.092736e-73  ...  3.775031e-11  2.753569e-05  0.999972
3        27  2.135088e-100   4.125332e-84  ...  9.357610e-14  1.370957e-06  0.999999
4        27  4.012965e-112   1.557370e-94  ...  2.319523e-16  6.825603e-08  1.000000
5        27  7.542484e-124  5.879283e-105  ...  5.749522e-19  3.398268e-09  1.000000
6        27  1.417632e-135  2.219508e-115  ...  1.425164e-21  1.691898e-10  1.000000
7        27  2.664479e-147  8.378943e-126  ...  3.532629e-24  8.423464e-12  1.000000
8        27  5.007966e-159  3.163164e-136  ...  8.756511e-27  4.193796e-13  1.000000
9        27  9.412616e-171  1.194137e-146  ...  2.170522e-29  2.087968e-14  1.000000
10       27  1.769128e-182  4.508027e-157  ...  5.380186e-32  1.039538e-15  1.000000
11       27  3.325128e-194  1.701841e-167  ...  1.333615e-34  5.175555e-17  1.000000
12       27  6.249673e-206  6.424678e-178  ...  3.305701e-37  2.576757e-18  1.000000
13       27  1.174644e-217  2.425402e-188  ...  8.194013e-40  1.282892e-19  1.000000
14       27  2.207777e-229  9.156221e-199  ...  2.031093e-42  6.387142e-21  1.000000
15       27  4.149581e-241  3.456597e-209  ...  5.034575e-45  3.179971e-22  1.000000
16       27  7.799257e-253  1.304912e-219  ...  1.247946e-47  1.583214e-23  1.000000
17       27  1.465893e-264  4.926217e-230  ...  3.093350e-50  7.882360e-25  1.000000
18       27  2.755188e-276  1.859713e-240  ...  7.667648e-53  3.924396e-26  1.000000
19       27  5.178455e-288  7.020668e-251  ...  1.900620e-55  1.953842e-27  1.000000

[20 rows x 11 columns]
```

Result for LinearRegression:

```
[30. 33. 36. 39. 42. 45. 48. 51. 54. 57. 60. 63. 66. 69. 72. 75. 78. 81.
 84. 87.]
```

Comment: can you specify what you find strange about the results, is that the first 19 rows all predict 27? Is it the format in which the predictions are returned? Thanks!

Comment: I find strange 27 in 19 rows, whereas I expected to [30. 33. 36. 39. 42. 45. 48. 51. 54. 57. 60. 63. 66. 69. 72. 75. 78. 81.
 84. 87.], as LinearRegression returned.
But since you mentioned, I'm not familiar with the retunred format either. If you could help, I'd appreciate it

Comment: for the format: you get the predicted probability for each class - the predicted label is chosen based on the class that has the highest probability. It may just be that a linear model is more appropriate to use than the NB - which may not perform well given the toy example. hope this helps!

Comment: I understand. Yeah, pretty helpful. Thank you